# search coordinate better rectangle on the board

Tags: python, rectangles

Guyz, pls help!

I have board WxH. And I need to place my rectangle (a x b) so that it doesn't overlap other rectangles

About coordinates:lower left - (0,0). upper right - (W, H). For each rectangle we know the coordinates of the lower left and upper right

Input: the first line is W, H and a, b. Second line n - number of another rectangles. Then the coordinates are written in n lines

Output: coordinate lower left x_a, y_a and upper right x_b, y_b. All numbers are int and non negative

Example

```
11 8 2 7

4

1 5 3 7

2 2 4 5

5 3 9 4

5 3 7 8
```

Answer : 9 0 11 8

Comment: Is this homework? You should not ask for solutions.

Comment: I'm studying for an exam. Similar issues will appear on it